# Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de usar pré-processadores css?

Tags: css, sass, less

Sempre ouço desenvolvedores falarem dos pré-processadores, mas ainda não encontrei artigos sobre as desvantagens e vantagens.

Também queria saber se é melhor usar o css puro ou pré-processado.

Comment: A pergunta é bacana, mas acho que tende a ir pro lado da opinião. **:/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara na minha opinião os pre-processadores são ótimos, fazem o que promete.

Onde os seus pontos positivos é passado por toda aquela facilidade e flexibilidade proposta para o nosso amigo CSS, que é uma linguagem que está evoluindo bastante em termos de codificar programação nas folhas de estilo.

Agora os seus contras é toda aquela questão de não serem nativas todas essas funções e possibilidades que os pre-processadores exerce sobre o nosso CSS, enfim.

Vale a pena escrever CSS puro para projetos pequenos porém bem estruturado e CSS extensivo modular para projetos maiores que faça sentindo usar essas features para melhorar o CSS.